# Set rails redirections from YML file

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, routes, url-routing

I currently have one YML file with a bunch of redirections URLs inside, following a simple syntax
`old_url: new_url`.

When I load this YML file on my app, I end up with a hash of keys and values.

At the moment, I'm not using this YML and all my redirections are added manually into a redirections file, which means I've got a very big file with more than 150 redirections added by hand, following this syntax:

`get 'old_url', to: redirect('new_url', status: 301)`

What I would like to do is to remove all these lines and use the "key/value" pairs that I have in my YML file instead.
What is the best way to do this?

I thought it would be as easy as iterating on my hash inside my redirections file, but it does not seem to work and I'm not sure that's a really clean way of doing it

Thanks a lot

Comment: It is as easy as iterating the hash inside the redirections file. Post some code. What have you tried so far. What should happen, what happened instead.

Comment: After digging a bit, it works, but it's actually just the spec that are not passing. I think that in this case i'm going to need to find another way of coding this as otherwise I won't be able to keep test passing

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following should work in your `config/routes.rb`:

```
redirects = YAML.load_file(Rails.root.join('path/to/redirects.yaml'))
redirects.each do |old, new|
  get old, to: redirect(new, status: 301)
end
```

Note that you need to change the path and file name to match the path and file name of your YAML file.

Comment: Raising a great point here. While routes has a very specific DSL, it's just a regular Ruby file and you can use regular Ruby syntax in it.

Comment: THanks, not sure why it was not working but probably some syntax problem!